# The keyboard does not work in Midnight Commander running on a remote computer via SSH

Tags: ssh, putty, midnight-commander, busybox

This is my first post on super user. I'm having a weird problem with Midnight Commander running remotely via SSH. The problem is that none of the keys work after running the mc via SSH running in the bash console, and the color of the mc is black and white. The problem does not occur when I connect to a remote system via PuTTY. The remote system is BusyBox v1.19.4 with an additional OpenWrt repository, I connect from a computer running Ubuntu. I am sending a screenshot showing two windows, the left one is not working properly, the right one is working properly. How to solve this problem? I find it much more convenient to use the bash console to connect to a remote system than PuTTY.

The left window doesn't work, the right one works fine

[image]

Comment: What happens when using `mc` with the [-c, --color](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc) switch?

Comment: When I use mc -c the color is blue yellow but the keys still don't work.

Comment: This might be a problem with the environment variables in SSH that define the keyboard. Compare the `TERM` variable in PuTTY and in MC. I believe the preferred value is `xterm`.

Comment: echo $TERM at PuTTY: xterm,      echo $TERM at SSH: xterm-256color

Comment: Did you try to change it to `xterm` before calling MC?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. I changed xterm-256color to xterm and everything works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the default value that SSH sets for the `TERM`
environment variable.

The value that works in PuTTY was `xterm`, but in SSH
the default value is `xterm-256color`.

Setting `TERM` to `xterm` before calling Midnight Commander (`mc`)
solved the problem.

Comment: That doesn't address the question (take a look at the output from `infocmp xterm xterm-256color` to see that there's no keyboard differences).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: The problem is surely not with Linux but with MC.

Comment: Actually read the source code, the only place where `TERM` would affect **MC** aside from external configuration not addressed in your answer, anything beginning "xterm" is [treated the same](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/cf7846cd62305a0fb2698b8f3648f1fd586c5f73/lib/tty/tty.c#L123)).

Comment: @ThomasDickey: Might be some bug elsewhere in the code, or a different version of MC. This suggestion solved the poster's problem, so I posted an answer, that's is all I know about it.